# Log file generated from start-transcript command producing TerminatingError(New-Item) multiple times

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have created a script which delete the blobs from azure storage account based on the retention period. I am generating a log file by using start-transcript. Along with script output it is capturing the below error multiple times.

`PS>TerminatingError(New-Item): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.Azure\AzInstallationChecks.json'."`

I have verified, there is no .Azure folder under systemprofile.
Please let me know how to fix this.

below is the script.

```
try {

$Logpath = "$PSScriptRoot\Logs"
$LogFileNameFormat = "Backup-Retention-$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm").log"
$LogFileName = "$Logpath\$LogFileNameFormat"
If (Test-Path $LogFileName) {
    Remove-Item $LogFileName -Force
    New-Item $LogFileName -ItemType file -Force
}
Else {
    New-Item $LogFileName -ItemType file
}
Start-Transcript $LogFileName
Import-Module AzureRM
$Params = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\Retention.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$StorageAccount = $Params.StorageAccount
$StorageAccountKey = $Params.Key
$StorageAccountContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$Blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $Params.ContainerName -Context $StorageAccountContext | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$splitstring = $Blobs | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Split($_, "/")[0]}
$datetimestring = $splitstring | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Split($_, "Backup-")[1]}
$datetimes = $datetimestring  | ForEach-Object {[datetime]::ParseExact($_, "yyyyMMdd-HHmm", $null)}
$retentiontimestamp = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Params.RententionPeriod)
$old_blobs = @()
"Checking for db backups older than $($Params.RententionPeriod) days."
foreach ($datetime in $datetimes)
{

    if ( $retentiontimestamp -gt $datetime)
    {

        $Blobs | foreach-object { 
            if($_ -match $datetime.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmm")) 
            {

                $old_blobs += Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $Params.ContainerName -Context $StorageAccountContext -Blob $_

            }
        } 
    }

}
if ($old_blobs.Count -gt 0)
{

    "below are the dumps exceed the retention period."
    "================================================="
    $old_blobs.Name
    "================================================="
    foreach($old_blob in $old_blobs)
    {

        "deleting $($old_blob.Name)"
        Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $old_blob.Name -Container $Params.ContainerName -Context $StorageAccountContext
    }
    "================================================="
}
else {
    "No blobs crossed the retention period."

}
}
catch {
Write-Output "$($Params.ClientName) Prod DB backup retention script failed : $($_.Exception.Message)"
Stop-Transcript
Send-Email -Message '<h3 style="color:#FF0000;"> $($Params.ClientName) Prod DB backup script failed. Please refer the attached logs for more information.</h3>' -Highpriority
}

try{
Stop-Transcript
Send-Email -Message "<h3 style='color:#00A90A;'>$($Params.ClientName) Prod DB backup retention script successfully executed. Please refer the attached logs for more information.</h3>"
  }
  catch{
Write-Output "$($Params.ClientName) Prod DB backup retention script: Failed to send email. $($_.Exception.Message)"
Stop-Transcript
  }
```

Comment: Do you have an example value of `$LogFileName` when it's executing? I know it is build in the code but it looks like `New-Item` tries to create `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.Azure\AzInstallationChecks.json` instead of the Logpath.

Comment: This is the path of log
"C:\DBBackupScript\Logs\Backup-Retention-2020-01-06-01-00.log"

Comment: @SumanGhosh, have you solved your issue now?

Comment: @IvanYang no, issue is till there. I will try the below solution and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I found that AzInstallationChecks.json is present in my local user profile.
I have copied the same file to above path which fixed the issue.